# PyTorch 2.0.1 installation error on Windows

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, torch

I am trying to install Pytorch on Python using pip:

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

I get the following Error:

> No matching distribution found for torch

The command should install the newest stable version of Pytorch (being 2.0.1).
I am using Python version 3.9.6 (64-bit version). The Pytorch get-started guide claims, that Pytorch supports Python versions 3.8-3.11.

Nethertheless I get the Error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `torch-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` is the built dist that exists for 3.9 with the platform tag `win_amd64` (you can see the full list of [platform compatibility tags](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/) of all built dists for that version [here](https://pypi.org/project/torch/2.0.1/#files)). Can you try checking `python -c "import platform; print(platform.architecture())"` to double check your platform?

Comment: I get: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: Do you get `win-amd64` from running `python -c "import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())"`? If it does, you can check `pip debug --verbose` to make sure one of your compatibility tags matches `cp39-cp39-win_amd64`

Comment: yes, one of my compatibility tags matches 'cp39-cp39-win_amd64'

Comment: If you navigate to the [page of dists](https://pypi.org/project/torch/2.0.1/#files) and download the `torch-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` wheel, you should be able to `pip install torch-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` (from whatever folder where you downloaded it to). Does it still give you an error?

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks a lot. In the meantime I also found out, that (somehow) my pip.ini file changed. And there was the origin of my problem...

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try...

- You might have multiple versions of Python installed on your machine, and `pip` and `python` could be pointing to different installations. `pip --version` and `python --version`. Do these yield the same version? If they do, you could see if they're from the same file location. Try `where python` and `where pip` on Windows, or `which python` and `which pip` on Linux and Mac. If they don't line up, then try `python -m pip install torch torchvision torchaudio`
- upgrade your pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, you might have outdated repositories
- download and install the wheels (`.whl`) directly with `pip install <wheel_path>`